# easiest way to "store" a function on a class without binding it?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I am writing some support code to expedite calling Django views (functions declared elsewhere) via RequestFactory.  I am storing most of the testing attributes directly on classes, rather than on their instances.

One thing I have to do is to store, on the class, is which function I am interested in, so that I can call it later (using **inspect** to feed it its correct parameters).

Here's my general intent:

```
def to_test(var1, var2, var3):
    "this function has nothing to do with MyTest"
    assert isinstance(var1, basestring), "not an instance"

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    #only using this attribute to store the function to 
    #test, not to bind that function
    func_under_test = to_test

    def test_with_abc(self):
        self.func_under_test("a","b", "c")

    def test_with_def(self):
        self.func_under_test("d","e", "f")
```

But as soon as I assign a function to a class it is bound to the class.

Which is great 99% of the time.  Just not here because it gets the wrong parameters when called.  Instead, on each class I have re-declare *something* so that I can assign the function to it, rather than directly on the class.  Even metaclasses do not help.

**Some sample code**

What I'd like is FunctionStore1/2's syntax.  The closest I've actually come are FunctionStore3/4/6, but they require you to remember copy & pasting the little `_` declaration each time.  No big deal, just hacky.

```
def regular_function(*args, **kwds):
    print ("    regular_function(%s)" % (locals()))

def regular_function2(*args, **kwds):
    print ("    regular_function2(%s)" % (locals()))

class FunctionStore1(object):
    "this fails, expecting an instance"
    func_to_check = regular_function

class FunctionStore2(object):
    "ditto"
    func_to_check = regular_function2

class FunctionStore3Works(object):
    "this works"

    def _(): pass
    _.func_to_check = regular_function


class FunctionStore4Works(object):
    """this too, but I have to redeclare the `_` each time
       can I use MetaClass?
    """

    def _(): pass
    _.func_to_check = regular_function2

class BaseTsupporter(object):
    "this doesnt help..."
    def _(): pass

class FunctionStore5(BaseTsupporter):
    "because there is no `_` here"

    try:
        _.func_to_check = regular_function
    except Exception, e:
            print ("\nno `_` on FunctionStore5:e:%s" % (e))

class FunctionStore6Works(object):
    "trying a dict"

    _ = dict(func_to_check=regular_function)

class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        res = super(MyMeta, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)
        #this works...
        res._ = dict()
        return res

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        super(MyMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)

try:
    class FunctionStore7Meta(object):
        "using meta"

        __metaclass__ = MyMeta

        try:
            _.update(func_to_check=regular_function)                
        except Exception, e:
            print ("\nno `_` dict on FunctionStore7:e:%s" % (e))

except Exception, e:
    print ("\nno luck creating FunctionStore7 class :( exception:\n  %s" % (e))

#never mind the locals() + globals() hack, that's because this code is actually in a function to 
#allow SO's indenting...
li_to_call = [(k,v) for k, v in (locals().items() + globals().items()) if k.startswith("FunctionStore")]
li_to_call.sort()

for name, cls_ in li_to_call:
    print ("\n calling %s" % (name))
    try:
        if getattr(cls_, "func_to_check", None):
            cls_.func_to_check(name)
        elif hasattr(cls_, "_") and hasattr(cls_._, "func_to_check"):
            cls_._.func_to_check(name)
        elif hasattr(cls_, "_") and isinstance(cls_._, dict) and cls_._.get("func_to_check"):
            cls_._["func_to_check"](name)
        else:
            print ("    %s: no func_to_check" % (name))

            if "Meta" in name:
                print("        even if %s does have a `_`, now:%s" % (name, cls_._))

    except Exception, e:
            print ("    %s: exception:%s" % (name, e))
```

**Output:**

```
no `_` on FunctionStore5:e:name '_' is not defined

no `_` dict on FunctionStore7:e:name '_' is not defined

 calling FunctionStore1
    FunctionStore1: exception:unbound method regular_function() must be called with FunctionStore1 instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

 calling FunctionStore2
    FunctionStore2: exception:unbound method regular_function2() must be called with FunctionStore2 instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

 calling FunctionStore3Works
    regular_function({'args': ('FunctionStore3Works',), 'kwds': {}})

 calling FunctionStore4Works
    regular_function2({'args': ('FunctionStore4Works',), 'kwds': {}})

 calling FunctionStore5
    FunctionStore5: no func_to_check

 calling FunctionStore6Works
    regular_function({'args': ('FunctionStore6Works',), 'kwds': {}})

 calling FunctionStore7Meta
    FunctionStore7Meta: no func_to_check
        even if FunctionStore7Meta does have a `_`, now:{}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to store the function on a class, rather than an instance? Also, this is only an issue in Python 2, since in Python 3, unbound methods no longer require the first argument be an instance of the class.

Comment: Well, because the class is a bit like all the *Meta* and *Model* classes you see in Django.  It stores test attributes like database to call, login credentials, the url and function to call.  Those attributes are fixed for the class and setting them on the instances would work but also just introduce boilerplate code.  This is Python 2, despite the print()s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the functions in `staticmethod`:

```
class FunctionStore1(object):
    "this fails, expecting an instance"
    func_to_check = staticmethod(regular_function)
```

Comment: Awesome!  Just what I was looking for.  Plus, I remember one of the Python "big dudes" writing that he didn't see a use case for **staticmethod**.  That'll show him ;-).

Comment: @JLPeyret: Well, the reason for not seeing a use case is that, if it's truly a static method (when called, has no reference to class or instance), it may as well not be attached to the class.

Answer (score 1):

There are three different ways that a function can belong to a class:

```
def _instance_method(self, *args):
    print('self:', self)
    print('instance_method args:', args, '\n')

def _class_method(cls, *args):
    print('cls:', cls)
    print('class_method args:', args, '\n')

def _static_method(*args):
    print('static_method args:', args, '\n')

class TestClass:
    instance_method = _instance_method
    class_method = classmethod(_class_method)
    static_method = staticmethod(_static_method)
```

An instance method is implicitly passed a reference to the instance. A class method is implicitly passed a reference to the class. A static method isn't passed either the instance or the class. The following usage is provided as an example:

```
tester = TestClass()

tester.instance_method('args')
# self: <__main__.TestClass object at 0x0000000002232390>
# instance_method args: ('args',) 

tester.class_method('args')
# cls: <class '__main__.TestClass'>
# class_method args: ('args',) 

tester.static_method('args')
# static_method args: ('args',)
```

Note that the same structure is often achieved using decorators when the functions are defined in the body of the class itself.

```
class TestClass:
    def instance_method(self, *args): pass

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls, *args): pass

    @staticmethod
    def static_method(*args): pass
```

Note that this is all just a mechanism for controlling what arguments are implicitly passed to a function. This is relevant in your case because you have a function that is defined independently of the class definition, thus it doesn't make sense for the instance or class to be passed to the function.

It should also be noted that it's possible to assign the function to the class directly, after the class definition is complete.

```
class FunctionStore1: pass
FunctionStore1.func_to_check = func_to_check
```

I personally think that this might be the best pattern for your case. It clearly shows that you are attaching the function in question to the class as member data. This pattern also allows the comfortable "there's no use case for `staticmethod`" perspective.

This can also be done using a decorator.

```
def bind_function(func):
    def wrapper(cls):
        setattr(cls, func.__name__, func)
        return cls
    return wrapper

def func_to_check(*args):
    print('args:', args, '\n')

@bind_function(func_to_check)
class TestClass: pass

TestClass.func_to_check('args')
# args: ('args',)
```

This is a nice pattern because you get to declare the function that you want to bind before the class definition, rather than after it where it's easy to miss. It also offers a lot of flexibility if you want to change things up. For example, you could made it so that instead of dynamically using `func.__name__` as the class attribute, you could use a static name. Or, you could allow multiple functions to be passed to the decorator (and perhaps even delegate determining the parameters).

Comment: I am familiar with declaring stuff on top of classes *after* their creation.  However, for legibility, the solution I was after needed to be included *within* the class's body - it is after all the function that is being tested by the unittest so it's the most important bit - not after it.